# Xcode 4 Equivalent For "Build & Debug?"

Tags: xcode, xcode4

There was a helpful option in Xcode 3 to build for debugging purposes, it would show some extra information in the console if the app would crash. Is there an equivalent in Xcode 4? Haven't found it yet.

Thanks a lot in advance!

**EDIT** Come on, there has to be at least ONE Xcode 4 convert who knows!

Comment: FWIW, less than one hour without a response hardly warrants an impatient bump...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Product > Debug > Activate Breakpoints (⌘Y)
2. Product > Run (⌘R)

Comment: Any time. Just here to help. :)

Comment: I would've gone for "Yep. It's called 'Run'." ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The Breakpoints Button next to the Scheme pop-up in the navbar does the same thing